# database restore to particular state for testing

Tags: oracle, postgresql, integration-testing, dbunit

We use an Oracle(or postgres) database and an application server to execute integration tests. To isolate each test from another one , the database schema is dropped and re-created before each test.

As you see this is a time taking process.  The application uses 100+ tables. We are thinking of writing custom sql to delete unwanted data from each tables. Is there a better way to save and restore database state?

( It appears [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) could do this, I have not tried it yet. )

A single test involves:

- create database schema.
- Start app server.
- Start multiple client applications.
- Execute and verify.

We have 5000 odd tests, taking 700 hours or so.  (we do it on a grid environment, finishes overnight)

Most of the tests uses small data sizes, say up to 10 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle Flashback allows you to restore a table at a specified time point using a simple SQL query.
The documentation is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008).

I don't know if Postgre has a similar feature.

Comment: What sort of performance did you see from using the Oracle flashback?

Answer (score 4):

What version of Oracle (enterprise 10g+ or standard)?  Assuming you're using Enterprise, you can use Flashback database.  You build out your baseline DB.  Then

```
create a guaranteed restore point
run your test
capture results somewhere outside the database
flashback database to restore point
start over
```

This should be enough to get you started.  If you want additional detail let me know.

Answer (score 3):

For PostgreSQL, I think using a template database is quicker than re-creating all tables individually.

Just create a new database with a different name than the one that you use normally (e.g. my_template_db) but with all tables that you need. You can put testdata in there as well.

When you run the test, drop the *database* that you want to test. Then re-create the test using the template.

```
DROP DATABASE my_test_db;
CREATE DATABASE my_test_db WITH TEMPLATE my_template_db;
```

There were some optimizations in 9.0 that would speed this up. So maybe that approach is faster than re-creating all tables through SQL.

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle, you can use this pl/sql package:
[snapshot.sql](https://gist.github.com/amirhadadi/a7b2076645deadbd07ee)

We have 500 tables, 30 of which are restored after each test, and it takes ~500ms on average.

Usage is extremely simple:

```
EXECUTE SNAPSHOT.TAKE_SNAPSHOT('snapshot name');
EXECUTE SNAPSHOT.RESTORE_SCHEMA('snapshot name');
```

Answer (score 1):

If each test fits in a single transaction, you can simply rollback. Is that an option?

Comment: Well that depends. Generally, I wouldn't suggest that. Some actions take place only when trying to commit a transaction. Doing an automatic rollback may oversee problems happening then.

Comment: we use  features like deferred constraints which makes it important to call commit. Yes, testing could have been with  your approach

Answer (score 1):

#### Questions

- What kind of database are we talking about?
- Is it a Multi-T size or just a few G?
- How much data is in it?
- How are constraints defined?
- How quick should this be done?
- How long do your tests take? (a few days or a few weeks)
- How much storage is available?
- How much updates are made during a test?
- What version database do you have?

#### Suggestions

- If you have plenty storage and not very many updates, try a flashback database.
- If you are testing on copies of the prod database, use cloning (and of course, data masking) (also a good test for the prod backup).
- If you have a nice test database with valuable test data in it, use backup/restore.
- If you have a version 11g database, configured with a physical standby database, you could try to test on a snapshot database.