# H2 database restore to particular state for testing

Tags: unit-testing, h2

We use H2 database to execute tests. To isolate each test from another one, the database schema and basic data-setup is dropped and re-created before each test.

Is it possible to create a restore-point after the first setup of the database and restore before each test the data of this point?

SCRIPT just creates a sql-file with all tables and datas. Not a big difference to our own initialization.

Question [database restore to particular state for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040362/database-restore-to-particular-state-for-testing) is the same, just for Oracle and Postgres.

Comment: What about: create the database and then then a backup (file backup). Before running each test, restore the backup? Is that too slow? In the future, for H2 version 1.4.x, it might be possible to (instead of restore) simply truncate the database file.

Comment: I thought because of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143369/does-the-h2-script-command-work-like-a-snapshot) that BACKUP is slower but after I reread the answer I should test BACKUP.

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but I find it is still relevant. AFAIK there is no restore-point support.

Here is a simple, yet fast approach to backup/restore.

Create a backup prior to running the first test:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:myDatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOG=0");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.execute("SCRIPT TO 'memFS:myDatabase.sql'");
stat.close();
conn.close();
```

Restore after each test:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:myDatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOG=0");
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
stat.execute("DROP ALL OBJECTS");
stat.close();
conn.close();

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:myDatabase;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=runscript from 'memFS:myDatabase.sql';LOG=0");
conn.close();
```

Note that `SHUTDOWN` command turned out to be faster than `DROP ALL OBJECTS`, but it caused some issues (connection pool unable to reestablish connection).

I would not say the above approach is slow, far from it. But with a large database and thousands of tests there is still room for improvement as the method above takes some time. I managed to achieve a few times faster backup/restore (~15ms for a DB with ~350 tables) manually composing a script performing `TRUNCATE TABLE`, `ALTER SEQUENCE` and do the `INSERT` of all initial data (needs `SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE` for cleanup/restore procedure to be really fast). The code is cumbersome but was worth the effort.

Comment: Worked nicely for me! Though I used `connection.createStatement().execute("RUNSCRIPT FROM 'memFS:myDatabase.sql'")` instead of INIT